# ¿Cómo ajustar el submenú derecho usando CSS?

Tags: html, css

Alguién sabe que estilos css utilizar para que el submenu se muestra en la parte derecha en la misma posición del li con el titulo?

```css
.nav .clase a {
                background-color:grey;
                color:black;
                text-decoration:none;
                padding:10px 12px;
                display:block;
            }
```

```html
<ul class= "nav">
 <li class="clase">
   <a routerLink="">title</a>
     <ul class='submenu4'>
       <li class"lastli">
         <a>submenu1</a>
       </li>
       <li class"lastli">
         <a>submenu2</a>
       </li>
     </ul>                         
 </li>
</ul>
```

ESPERADO:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

COMO LO MUESTRA:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: como funciona esto? como se abre el sub menu: :hover o haciendo click con javaScript?

Comment: Hola Narciso, El ejemplo de la imagen permanece abierto pero la implementación que haria si seria con un hover:                                                                                  .nav .clase .submenu4{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    min-width:140px;
   }
  


   .nav .clase:hover > .submenu4 {
    display:block;
   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hola feliz año nuevo Tania**

Hay muchas formas de hacer con *css*, y la forma que hice lleva bastante códigos.

Estructura básica del HTML.
Tengo el **li** `clase` padre, y dentro el hijo **ul** `submenu` que esta oculto:

```
<li class="clase">
 <a class="abrir" href="#">Abrir submenu</a>
 
 <ul class="submenu">
  <li class="lastli"><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
 </ul>
 
</li>
```

Lo primero es definir un *width* al **li** padre que contiene el sub menú, una posición relativo, para que el sub menú dependa de este.

```
.clase {
 position: relative;
 width: auto;
 min-width: 140px;
 height: 50px;
}
```

Luego dentro del **li** padre se agrega el sub menú, para que funcione el `hover`.
Entonces ponemos al sub menú absoluto para sacar fuera de su contenedor padre con `left: 100%`, y ocultar con `width:0` y `height:0`.

```
.clase .submenu {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 top: 0;
 left: 100%;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
}
```

Y este ejemplo con mas códigos adicionales ya te va servir mucho.

```css
*,html,body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
}

ul,li {
list-style: none;
}

.nav {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding: 5px 5px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #000;
}

.clase {
display: inline-flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
position: relative;
margin: 0 5px;
width: auto;
min-width: 140px;
height: 50px;
background-color: violet;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.clase a, .routerLink a, .lastli a {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.clase .submenu {
display: block;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
left: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
width: 0;
height: 0;
background-color: green;
}

.nav .clase:hover .submenu {
padding: 0 5px 5px 5px;
min-width: 140px;
height: auto;
}

.lastli {
display: inline-flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
position: relative;
margin: 3px 0;
padding: 5px 5px;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css">
</head>
<body>

<ul class="nav">

    <li class="clase"><a href="#">title</a></li>
    
    <li class="clase"><a href="#">title</a></li>

    <li class="clase">
        <a class="abrir" href="#">Abrir submenu</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="lastli"><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
            <li class="lastli"><a href="#">submenu2</a></li>
            <li class="lastli"><a href="#">submenu3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="clase"><a href="#">title</a></li>

    <li>title</li>

</ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Feliz año Narciso Aifuz!, tú respuesta me ayudo mucho, muchas gracias